# Run Python Script Using Cygwin Crontab on Windows

Tags: python, cron

I succeed in setting up Cygwin Crontab on Windows. I need to run Python script every 5 minutes.

```
*/5 * * * * run-one C:\Python27\Scripts\myScript.py >  C:\Python27\Scripts\myScript.log 2>&1
```

Above didn't work in crotab. Also the log file  `cygstart cron.log` is empty. How I'm suppose to fix and run the script?

P.S. Script is running fine using idle editor.

Comment: You may have to add `C:\Python27\python` before the `C:\Python27\Scripts\myScript.py > ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your script directly in the Cygwin command line:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\myScript.py > C:\Python27\Scripts\myScript.log 2>&1
```

If it does not work, you may need to specify python.exe directly and use forward slash ("/") rather than backslash ("\"):

```
C:/Python27/python.exe C:/Python27/Scripts/myScript.py > C:/Python27/Scripts/myScript.log 2>&1
```

If it works, then please make sure cron is running. If it is running, it should give similar output as below:

```
$ cygcheck.exe -c | grep cron
cron                      4.1-61             OK
cron-debuginfo            4.1-61             OK

$ cygrunsrv -Q cron
Service             : cron
Display name        : Cron daemon
Current State       : Running
Controls Accepted   : Stop
Command             : /usr/sbin/cron -n

$ ps -lef | grep cron
  SYSTEM    4852    4680 ?        15:16:50 /usr/sbin/cron
```

If it is not running, run

```
$ cygrunsrv --start cron
```

If there is an error, you may need to reinstall cron.

```
$ cyglsa-config
```

Then

```
$ cron-config
```

And follow the instructions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helpful answer. The script is running well directly in the Cygwin command line. and I checked cron it's also running. but once I install a new crontab to run the script automatically, it doesn't work. Any idea?